# cold boot : the host gpu has changed

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studio to debug my application,when I install my app in the `AVD pixel2 API 21`, it get following error

`cold boot : the host gpu has changed`

but before this, I did not change anything.

I tried to change the AVD boot option to `cold boot`, and the error disappeared.

I want to know **what is the difference between cold boot and quick boot and why this error occurs ?**

thank you

Comment: read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#snapshots) to know about cold boot vs quickboot, I do not know the reason for the error, my guess is something related to your graphics card.